# Is it possible to stub or mock a method of a class under test?

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

In this `Scala` class

```
class A{
def a() = {b();}
def b() = {...}
}
```

If I want to test `a()`, is it possible to mock or stub `b()`

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Comment: Possible yes, using any mocking library with support for **Scala**. Recommended, it depends, many people _(including myself)_ would say that mocks are a bad idea and that should should rather restructure your code so that you can pass a dummy implementation of `b()`. Others will just use mocking libraries in any case.

Comment: Thanks Luis but aren't mocks sort of a dummy implementation itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocks override *all* methods (usually with *return `null` unless explicitly stated to return something else*) while here you want to override just *one* method. Since your class isn't `final` it would be easier to do something like

```
val tested: A = new A {
  override def b = ...
}
```

than mock it (actually mocking `final` classes is also impossible without something like PowerMock)

```
val tested = mock[A]
(tested.b _) returning (...)
// tested.a returns null and ignores b
```

because `mock` would also override `a` making your tests useless. You could "fix" it by mocking `a` to have the same implementation as the original... but this is absurd for many reasons.

So mocking method of a tested class with a mocking framework is possible but it's getting in the way rather than helping.